# TypeScript - Return type based on input type

Tags: typescript

I have a union type that can be narrowed based on a `kind` property. I would like to create a function whose input is one of those kinds (`"Foo"` or `"Bar"`), and whose output is a function that accepts the matching type as input (`FooType` or `BarType`).

I tried implementing such a function (`getHandler`) as follows:

```
type FooType = { kind: "Foo", fooMsg: string }
type BarType = { kind: "Bar", barMsg: string }

function getHandler(kind: "Foo" | "Bar") {
  switch (kind) {
    case "Foo":
      return { handle: (foo: FooType) => console.log(foo.fooMsg) };
    case "Bar":
      return { handle: (bar: BarType) => console.log(bar.barMsg) };
  }
}

const fooBar: FooType | BarType = getFooOrBar(); // return type is 'FooType | BarType'
getHandler(fooBar.kind).handle(fooBar);
```

But this throws an error on the call to `handle(fooBar)`:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'FooType | BarType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

I understand the error, but I'd like to know if there's a way to communicate to TypeScript that this will not fail (without resorting to using `any` or `//@ts-ignore`).

Specifically, because `getHandler` was called using fooBar's `kind`, I know that the `handle` function will be able to operate on fooBar. Is there a way express that fact in TypeScript?

Comment: You need a `default` clause in your switch statement, that should fix it. Even though TS would give you a different error if you use a kind other than "Foo" or "Bar" when calling `getHandler`, this way you always have it return an object w/a handle function.

Comment: A `default` clause is not needed here. Because `kind` is typed as `"Foo" | "Bar"` TypeScript can recognize that each possibility is handled by one of the case statements – meaning a default case is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the `{handle: ...}` function wrapper, but it should work in any case. The important bit is in the signature of getHandler.

In particular, in the usage of mapped types to build the `Handlers<...>` generic type:

```js
type Handlers<TypesWithKind extends { kind: string }> = {
    [T in TypesWithKind as T["kind"]]: (obj: T) => void;
}
```

I could not figure out a way to avoid a (albeit safe) cast in the `return` statements in the `getHandler` method, but I think it should be ok.

Link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKBvKBrAlgOwBMAuKAInjjIBooAzBAWQGcBzU54AJwNagF8AsAChQkKACEAhl2Tj0WPEVJlpXGlABGMluyice%20PkOEix0SmrlpYCa1AA%20kmdYDcIkQHpP%20iBFIAFsDAYMzE3gDuUQB05swAxjxgwAA2UkbRcFysnoRw8cyeAemEmgjYngBMngC2UmCQhAC0cdFBNSkAxNgQIE1cEHUNvE0AbrhSTVLMZihQABIlKRBczAA81swA6rjAAQDSBIRQEAAewBBEzJg4RxzcvAIAfFAKIlAfUADaiFAEUJsdntDkQoNMAV8yEpCGQALqw0gACjgmgAVqREABKV4vUZwXCEdzCEyzcSWGSLIjLVavBZLFbrSj2JxWFBPIkiOgAV3w8WAuDg%20CgrAgwEphGpGxO50uhGuiKZcxZLhQmK%20AHJoerYU9EdCMZjSOSuOLqcwvuY4HRbkRYZh3p9mBFdvEAlA9UdsRgHZ9PvFptAKAgyMQfb7w94oAEVtBEABlP7XeKC7nMCDHKRlLnAKB7aDmKBWm2EaJQACSOdw104uBSKSgA2TrHwuAAXumwdd1ZR1Y4oOq1L2CJwIFJjkXmLgamAUiBbHBomHw59I2WtFJa4Xs1BnXswVB-ZxaBEArhXYni4XrZouTUaitaDec2vmFyGnA0zvoDJoDUstACAuAYR2Of48wPKQ60eMAZGAJdlwbUUuS4IVEURBg4CNOxVRxG5k3wZg4GWaIUjgVh0IQaIMN0TFXAEbFwWNU0GQtFAi2hWEiQQiDP1UGQQ3g5cBmAZDUMRbQuFIVlIGxVAXgwfDCOI0jyIk6IJJouj%20AY64mPpVZWMgdijk4wSoEICA6CkLkUmAUNhG4309i4OAIigfAIDcgBRLgXK4RF1QAVQ805ID5dMADVIK5CAAEJ1VosMTBJYRFJzKRKCwpAlWcWQ5jeBzPn1chKA0ai2FIdVGAgZhmCkEV1REfgiTS%20gEGYrhaRFMV9MRDLKOhTFOXa3r%20rgRLTFSwVODBNQpJVeR7UKj5ir49RHx0Cr%202q2r6ogRriRa6acwkjqutFDq%20rUaJBqJU7RrUCavB8EA4C5A83pSDMUkI-QpxnOcuU-dJCzRCA%20Xs1riipBksrUDrrgK31MvdDCsusWT5I%20giiIgEiyIohdytYWiBGoMM5vdCT5rymTcIU6bcfx1SZHUzaSa0pqiWhiUWLGm6TL6ygJqAA)

```js
type FooType = { kind: "Foo", fooMsg: string }
type BarType = { kind: "Bar", barMsg: string }

type FooBarType = FooType | BarType;

// see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as
type Handlers<TypesWithKind extends { kind: string }> = {
    [T in TypesWithKind as T["kind"]]: (obj: T) => void;
}

type FooBarHandlers = Handlers<FooType | BarType>;

function getHandler<T extends (FooType | BarType)['kind']>(kind: T): FooBarHandlers[typeof kind] {
    switch (kind) {
        case "Foo":
            // here TS is confused about the type of kind. It is still recognized as 'Foo' | 'Bar' instead of simply Foo.
            // I bail out with a cast, which is kind of bummer, but I suppose we are more interested in the calling part
            return ((foo: FooType) => { console.log(foo.fooMsg); }) as FooBarHandlers[typeof kind];
        case "Bar":
            return ((bar: BarType) => {console.log(bar.barMsg); }) as FooBarHandlers[typeof kind];
        default:
            throw new Error('UnexpectedValue!');
    }
}

const aFoo: FooType | BarType = {
    kind: "Foo", fooMsg: 'Message'
};
const fooHandler = getHandler(aFoo.kind)
fooHandler(aFoo);

const aBar: BarType = {
    kind: "Bar", barMsg: 'Message'
};
const barHandler = getHandler(aBar.kind);
barHandler(aBar);

// you could also simply use an object:
const handlers: FooBarHandlers = {
    Foo: (foo: FooType) => { console.log(foo.fooMsg); },
    Bar: (bar: BarType) => {console.log(bar.barMsg); }
};
handlers[aFoo.kind](aFoo);
```

Comment: This almost works, but Typescript is using the knowledge that `aFoo` is a `FooType`. If you try to do `handlers[fooBar.kind](fooBar)` where the specific type of `fooBar` can't be determined then the same error occurs as described in the question. For example, add `function f(fooBar: FooBarType) { handlers[fooBar.kind](fooBar); }` to the end of your TS Playground. (TS Playground urls are too long to put in comments, sorry)

Comment: If you don't know that fooBar is a FooType, you possibly need to use custom type guards. The solution I provided _is_ a solution for the problem you are describing. If the problem you described is not the problem you need to solve, I suggest you edit the question to better describe what you _really_ need.

Comment: I mean: if you don't know the type of the object (you have a `any` or `unknown` as an input) you can just do `handlers[v['kind']]?.(v)` and go on ;) If you can't really guarantee what's inside `v`, the bulk of your problem regards input validation and not type inference.

Comment: In the question `fooBar` is type `FooType |  BarType`. The solution you provided only works if `fooBar` can be narrowed to either `FooType` or `BarType`. Even though your solution includes `const aFoo: FooType | BarType = ...`, typescript still knows that `aFoo` can be narrowed to `FooType`. I have update the question to make this distinction more clear.

Comment: Sorry, my wording in my previous comment is a bit wrong. The point is that `aFoo` is _already narrowed_ to `FooType`, even though it was declared as `FooType | BarType`.

Comment: If it-s not narrowed, there is no point in exposing a typed handler. Re-read my previous comment: you would just need a single `handle(obj: FooType | BarType)` function, roughly implemented as `handlers[obj['kind']]?.(obj)`.